# Import git project (as a bare repository) to GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a production git server which holds bare repositories for our projects (not working directories!). We want to migrate to GitLab and upload these projects to our new GitLab server.

I found the simplest solution is clone to some folder and push to GitLab. 
But - After cloning a project to a local "fff" folder I compared the new working directory, in "fff" folder, with the working directory on the git server and found some files are missing. I don't know if is the missing items are important or not.

Does cloning to some folder and pushing to GitLab is safe enough, or would you recommend other solution?

Comment: What files? However, this should be OK. Git would be a useless decentralized VCS system otherwise.

Comment: You don't need to clone at all — you can push directly from a bare repo. But of course files that are not in commits (perhaps they are listed in `.gitignore`) will not be pushed.